# Why do you need these characters in the regex in this Elixir regex match?

Tags: regex, elixir

I came across a method such as:

```
  @spec split_words(String.t) :: [String.t]
  defp split_words(text) do
    Regex.scan ~r/(*UTF)[\p{L}0-9-]+/i, text
  end
```

It's really to be able to pass the following test:

```
  test "German" do
    expected = %{"götterfunken" => 1, "schöner" => 1, "freude" => 1}
    assert Words.count("Freude schöner Götterfunken") == expected
  end
```

What is `(*UTF)` - is that Elixir specific or a regex concept?  I'm guessing it's to "cast" the string to UTF encoding.  And what about `\p{L}` - is this an "expander" of some kind to let you know to use an alphabet that includes the umlaut character?

I saw it in this repository: https://github.com/alxndr/exercism/blob/master/elixir/word-count/word_count.exs#L25

Answer (score 4):

No, `(*UTF)` tells the PCRE regex engine (probably the one used in Elixir) to read the target string as an UTF-8 encoded string (otherwise the string is read one byte at once). But it doesn't cast the target string.

`\p{L}` is a unicode character class that contains all letters (in all alphabets, with or without accents).

more infos here: http://pcre.org/original/pcre.txt

Comment: Note: regex101.com says (*UTF) and (*UTF8) are unknown verbs, so I would guess it's specific to this regex flavor, and not all PCRE flavors

Comment: regex101 doesn't support `(*UTF)` and `(*UTF8)`, that's all. It's a PCRE feature.

Comment: Is it really a bug? regex101 is only a tool for test and training. You can add it in a wishlist if any. Note that the pcre library can be compiled to handle more or less UTF encoding. But note that regex101 supports the u modifier (so It can support `(*UTF8)`)

Comment: Well, it would be better if it didn't die when encountering it, or it at least gave a more helpful message... It gives a similar message in Perl when I tried.